# how to access fourth level gridview in asp.net c#

Tags: gridview, nested

I Have Access "gvDepartments", "gvFuctions" & "gvSections"
How can i access the "gvEmployees"?

C# Code:

protected void Show_Hide_EmployeesGrid(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton imgShowHide = (sender as ImageButton);

```
    GridViewRow row = (imgShowHide.NamingContainer as GridViewRow);
    if (imgShowHide.CommandArgument == "Show")
    {
        row.FindControl("pnlEmployees").Visible = true;
        imgShowHide.CommandArgument = "Hide";
        imgShowHide.ImageUrl = "~/images/minus.png";
        string empId =  (row.NamingContainer as GridView).DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();             
        GridView gvEmployees = row.FindControl("gvEmployees") as GridView;
        BindEmployees(empId, gvEmployees);  
        //gvEmployees.
    }
    else
    {
        row.FindControl("pnlEmployees").Visible = false;
        imgShowHide.CommandArgument = "Show";
        imgShowHide.ImageUrl = "~/images/plus.png";
    }
}
```

ASP.NET

Comment: can you clarify more what's your problem. i did the same nested gridview and with same logical you do and it works for me.